# How to make a while loop in iMacros?

Tags: wordpress, imacros

I am making a iMacros script to extract every single title from post list of wp-admin of wordpress. They have the same element:

`<a class="row-title" href="https://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=239&amp;action=edit" aria-label="“Name” (Edit)">Name</a>`

I have made a script that can extract one of [Name]

```
VERSION BUILD=12.0.501.6698
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00

URL GOTO=https://website.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=movies
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=class:row-title* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=example.csv
```

I figured out if I replace value of [POS], for example with POS=1, I will get 1st [Name], POS=2 I will get 2nd [Name] and so on. But I don't know how to make a while loop in iMacros that do:

1, Replace POS=POS+1

2, Loop it until the end of the list of posts

3, Click the next page (actually I think I can figure out this step but since I am stuck on 1 and 2 so I didn't do this)

Please help. Thank you. 
By the way is there any way to program iMacros in C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION BUILD=12.0.501.6698
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.00

'Set loop, start at tag 1
SET !LOOP 1

URL GOTO=https://website.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=movies

'POS= Loop option, now POS change the number 1,2,3,4,5,6,etc.
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=class:row-title* EXTRACT=TXT
```